# add active class to bootstrap tab on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have `one button` and `bootstrap tab`.

> on click of button want to add class active to first tab element.

I'm generating all tab elements dynamically , and want to active only very first tab element on button click.
    MyButton

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li><a href="#divArea1" data-toggle="tab">div1<i class="fa"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#divArea2" data-toggle="tab">div2 <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/jx5q5u68/1), clicking the button you have the first tab with class `active`:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#divArea1" data-toggle="tab">div1<i class="fa"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#divArea2" data-toggle="tab">div2 <i class="fa"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<button class="btn btn-default clickme">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clickme').click(function () {
        $('.nav-tabs li:first').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#MyButton').click(function() {
 $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');
});
```